How to decompose a specific constraint in the sub-problem?
I am trying to solve a scheduling problem related to the line balancing systems with the aim of column generation (price & branch). The simplified compact formulation would be:
\begin{align*}
\text{Min}_{(compact)} \quad & \sum_s y_s \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \sum_s x_{j,s} = 1 \quad  \forall j \\
\quad & \sum_j P_j x_{j,s} \leq Ct.y_s \quad  \forall s \\
\quad & \sum_s s. x_{j,s} \leq \sum_s s. x_{k,s} \quad  \forall (j,k) \\
                        & x_{j,s},\ y_s \in \{0,1\}
\end{align*}
where indices $j,k$ referred to the tasks, index $s$ indicates stations, $Ct$ is the predetermined cycle time, $x_{j,s}$ is the assigning variable, and $y_s$ is for opening a station if needed.
By substituting the variable $x_{j,s}$ by $\sum_p x_{j,s}^p \lambda_s^p$, (I assumed the pricing problem is closed and bounded since there are no rays), then reformulating by Dantzig-Wolfe, the relaxed master problem would be:
\begin{align*}
\text{Min}_{(mp)} \quad & \sum_s y_s = \sum_s \sum_p \lambda_{s}^p \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \sum_s \sum_p x_{j,s}^p \lambda_{s}^p = 1 \quad \forall j \quad (\pi_j)\\
\quad & \sum_s \sum_p s.x_{j,s}^p \lambda_{s}^p \leq \sum_s \sum_p s.x_{k,s}^p \lambda_{s}^p \quad \forall (j,k) \quad (\sigma_{j,k})\\
\quad & \sum_p \lambda_{s}^p \leq 1 \quad \forall s \quad (\delta_{s}) \\
                        & \lambda_{s}^p \geq 0.
\end{align*}
where I would like to decompose the problem based on each station $s$. In order to generate a column, the pricing problem is as follows:
\begin{align*}
\text{Min}_{(sp)} \quad & 1 - (\sum_j \pi_j x_j) - (\sum_j \sum_k s. \sigma_{j,k} (x_{j} - x_{k})) - \delta_s  \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \sum_j P_j x_{j} \leq Ct\\
                        & x_{j} \in \{0,1\}
\end{align*}
A simple example to reproduce the data and the solution would be:


Now, my questions are:

I doubt the pricing term related to the sub-problem precedence constraint may capture what I want, specifically to define the required sets for $j$ and $k$. Do you have any references for that?
I think, the sub-problem still needs some tweaks to really make the appropriate columns for the precedence part. May I have your insight on that?
I am unsure to understand being the index $s$ in the sub-problem. As I want to decompose the problem based on each station, the sub-problem needs to be solved separately. Is it necessary to apply the index $s$ in the implementation phase?


Dear @RobPratt, may I have your insight?

Are you able to share data?

Mostly correct, but you have a few issues.

Spell out DW as Dantzig-Wolfe for clarity.
In the master problem, $\lambda_k^p$ should be $\lambda_s^p$.
In the subproblem, each $x$ variable also needs an $s$ index.
In the subproblem, you have mistakenly omitted the $s$ coefficient in the $\sum_j \sum_k$.
Yes, I think you can omit the convexity constraint, which will naturally be satisfied at optimality.


Dear @RobPratt, I just updated the question. Actually, my main worries came back to the correct definition of the pricing term for precedence constraint as well as how to deal with index $s$ in the sub-problem. (Objective and constraint).

So $Ct=20$ and the optimal objective value is $4$? Yes, you can omit the $s$ index for $x$ in the subproblem. In fact, you can share a column pool across stations because the subproblem constraints do not depend on $s$.

Dear @RobPratt, thanks. The optimal number of stations is 4. Can we ommit index $s$ because the resources are identical?

Also, what about coefficient $s$ in the second term of the sub problem? Can I ommit that?

For the subproblem for each $s$, you can omit $s$ in the index of $x$ because you are solving a separate problem for each $s$.  But you cannot omit the $s$ objective coefficient in the subproblem.  Because of the precedence constraints, the stations are not identical, even though the subproblem constraints are identical.

Dear @RobPratt, thanks. It's somewhat new for mine. Please, let me check something and will get back to you. ()

Dear @RobPratt, I have some difficulties playing around with the parameter $x_{j,s}^p$ which will be valued by the sub-problem. As each extreme point of the sub-problem is a feasible pattern, Actually how a task $i$ can appear on the pattern $p$, what exactly does $x_{j,s}^p$ mean? (I am unsure to understand its structure when I try to give an initial value for that). May I have your insight?

I mean from the implementation, should not it be $x_{j}^p$?

When you solve the subproblem for station $s$ and find a negative reduced cost column, you increment the pattern count $p$ for that $s$ and introduce the constant coefficient $x_{j,s}^p$ from the value of the variable $x_j$.

Dear @RobPratt, thanks. If I understand correctly when we solve the sub-problem we implicitly count index $s$ and there is no long to explicitly count that. Something like we say $x_{j,p}$. We count an appropriate column by extending the column index $p$ and add the value of $x_j$ to the added column. Am I standing in the right way?

Yes, that is the most straightforward way. As a possible improvement (mentioned in my first August 29 comment), you can exploit the fact that the subproblem constraints do not depend on $s$. When you generate a new column for station $s$, it can also be used at any other station, so you can share a common column pool across stations. Doing so might reduce the number of outer iterations needed.
